# Inline block increase spacing between elements and keep the alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to increase the space between elements within an inline block container. I found a trick to do that but it works only for the first line...
By the way, I have n number of elements and a specific container width.

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                background-color: blue;
                height: 300px;
                width: 620px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .container div + div {
                margin-left: 33px;
            }

            .child1 {
                width:200px;
                height: 100px;
                display:inline-block;
                background-color: red;
            }

            .child2 {
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: green;
            }

            .child3 {
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="child1"></div>
            <div class="child2"></div>
            <div class="child3"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Result:**
[image]

(Note: It has to support all browsers, +IE7)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nth-child` selector to select every three child!

https://jsfiddle.net/25x4ga0g/1/

```
.container div:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

[More about nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use something fantastic called Flexbox.

First, set the container to `display: flex`. Then use `flex-wrap: wrap` so if you add more elements, they will appear on a new row below. Also make sure to use `align-content: flex-start` so the elements will start from the left.
Finally add a margin-left and margin-bottom to all your child-divs so they will have space between them. Because we are use Flexbox, your problem with the margin will now be eliminated.

If you want the divs to fit perfectly in the container instead, just remove the margins of the child-divs and set the parent to `justify-content: space-between`.

**CSS Code:**

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-content: flex-start;
   width: 620px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: blue;
}

.container div {
   margin-right: 33px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.child1 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   display:inline-block;
   background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: green;
}

.child3 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noen5deq/)

[Read more about Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

An alternate solution if you don't want to use Flexbox, you could just select every third children and then set the margin-left to 0:

```
.container div:nth-child(3n) {
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-right` instead of `margin-left`.

```
.container div {
  margin-right: 33px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 620px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container div {
  margin-right: 33px;
}
.child1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.child2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
.child3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work since I need to have the correct margins in both edges of the container... (I need the space just in the middle)

Comment: Seems to be giving the expected result. Can you give an example DOM where you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, just inspect the container element, and make the width smaller, (double click and scroll it)  and you will notice that the element is going down when the container width hits the margin not the actual child.. And I don't want that..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
div+div:last-of-type{
            margin:0px;
        }
```

Insert this snippet in the style part and it should be ok. It will work for the last div only .